# Why the method is not overridden?

Tags: ruby

For example we have:

```
module X
 def test
  "X"
 end
end

module Y
 def test
  "Y"
 end
end

class L
 include X
end

L.new.test #=> "X"

class L
 include Y
end

L.new.test #=> "Y"

class L
 include X
end

L.new.test #=> "Y"
```

Here's the strange thing. Why the last include didn't change the method to X's method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby does not allow to include one module twice, attempt to do it second time is just ignored.

From documentation of [Module#append_features](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Module#append_features-instance_method) which is used by `Module#include` under the covers:

> Ruby's default implementation is to add the constants, methods, and module variables of this module to mod if this module has not already been added to mod or one of its ancestors.

Comment: But why it calls 'included' module callback every time when module is including in class?

Comment: Look at `Module#include` source. It first calls `append_features`, and then, regardless of whether module was actually included by it or not, calls `included` hook.